# Resource not found when creating overridden version of Tform

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm creating my own form with some additional properties. I've created a constructor for this form which attempts to use the inherited constructor. I've tried my constructor both with and without overload. Either way, when I actually try to create an instance of the form at runtime, I get an error "Resource TChronPanelForm not found". The error occurs when I try to call the inherited constructor.

```
type
  TChronPanelForm = class(TForm)
    public
      MainBox:TScrollBox;
      isLoaded: boolean;
      constructor create(AOwner: TComponent); override; // have tried w/ and w/out override
      // more may come here, but left it at this to make initial attempt simple
    private
      {}
  end;

// here is my constructor
{ TChronPanelForm }

constructor TChronPanelForm.create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(aOwner);
  // the above line is where the error occurs
  isLoaded := false;
  ...
end;

// And then at run time this creates an instance
// from within another class:
...
  var
    aForm: TChronPanelForm;
begin
  aForm := TChronPanelForm.create(DockSite);
  ...
```

Appreciate any clarification you might give. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if related, but you shouldn't define your constructor where it is before private. That area's reserved for the IDE only. Instead, that belongs under public. On that same note, if `MainBox` is something you dropped in the form designer, that must be defined before private.

Comment: @JerryDodge: I tried the constructor in the top section and in the public section. Didn't make a difference. And there is no form designer; I was trying to create this form entirely at run time rather than having a designed form. A workaround would be to create a design time version of the form, but I really wanted to figure out how to do the whole thing at run time.

Comment: Defining the constructor where I mentioned isn't a recommendation - it's a requirement. It *must* be under `public`.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `override` instead of `overload` ?  And the constructor should be in the public section..

Comment: @John Good catch, `override` is what OP needs here. `overload` is only meant if you want to provide more than one version of the same method.

Comment: @JohnEasley: You are right. Unfortunately, that doesn't fix the problem. But I will correct the code sample above so these errors don't distract others.

Comment: @JohnEasley. Thanks. If you want to add that as an answer, I'll mark as solution. Appreciate the help. (I wondered if an answer might be here, but none of my searches found it.)

Comment: @Eric thanks, but I'd rather you up vote the existing answer on the prior  question..